# Archiving to remote-machine with tar/cpio and ssh?

Tags: ssh, tar, cpio

I'm renting a couple of VPS with Ubuntu, and I've managed to fill-up one of them.  Here I've got several directories with lots of files I'd like to put into an archive.  Unfortunately, I don't have room enough to create such an archive (not even as root).

I was therefor wondering if it's possible to use tar (preferred) or cpio to create the archive on the other VPS?  I'll want to compress the archive, so either calling `tar` with the j-option (bzip2) or piping the file to `bzip2` at some point (preferably before sending it over the network) - any suggestions as to  how I best can compress the file?

Finally, both VPS got ssh and sshd installed, so I was thinking of using it for the transmission of the file.

+++

Unfortunately I'm not an expert in using tar/cpio or ssh in this way, so I'm a bit out of my depth as to something like this can (best) be accomplished.  How should I use `ssh`?  Like tunnel or pipe, like ftp, like scp?  How should I use `tar`?  Have `tar` running on both VPS, with a ssh-tunnel between them?  Run tar on the source-VPS, tunnel the result and redirect the result to a file on the destination-VPS?

So how can I do this?

Are there other - better - way to do something like this?  Some special-purpose package? Using network-sockets?  Something else?

Comment: `sshfs` is the first thing that comes to my mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

piping should be enough. Doing just:

```
tar -cvj /path/to/your/files | ssh remote "cat > file.tar.bz2"
```

(if you have set up passwordless log in using keys)

Later on the other machine you can decompress the received file using `tar -xvf path.tar.bz2 -C ./`

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this to archive and copy through ssh:

```
tar zcvf - stuff/ | ssh alex@localhost 'cat - > /tmp/stuff.tar.gz'
```

Here you are creating a tar.gz archive but instead of saving it to some file you are using **-** which is standard output. 
The standard output **-** is then piped to ssh and from there on you cat from standard output **cat - >** and redirect to your file on the second machine.

The suggestion form user Arkadiusz Drabczyk in the comments is also good, because once set up you could use **mv** to move from one machine to the other.
If you want to use sshfs you have to install it first and after that:

```
sudo sshfs root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ /mnt/droplet
```

Answer (score 0):

I would always use `rsync` for cases like this. It makes the whole process more flexible and reliable. For example the whole process will be restartable and can continue where it stopped / failed / was interrupted.